If $|C(g)|>|G|/2$, then g$\in Z(G)$?
I'm having trouble solving an exercise on characters of finite groups and I don't know what to do as I don't even understand the idea behind it.
The question goes as follows :
Let G be a finite group .If there exists $g\in G$ such as $\sum_{i=1}^{k}|\chi_i(g)|^2 > \frac{|G|}{2}$, where $\chi_1,...,\chi_k$ are the only irreducible characters of G,then $g\in Z(G)$.
First of all and the reason I'm a bit confused is that if the above is true ,then according to orthogonality relations : $|C(g)|>\frac{|G|}{2}$.I can't understand why this really matters or helps with the question so I ignored it and continued with another tactic :
If $\chi_i$ are irreducible characters for every $i\in\{{1,...,k}\}$ then of course $<\chi_i,\chi_i>=1$ ,that means that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}<\chi_i,\chi_i>=k\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{|\chi(g_j)|}{|C(g_j)|}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{|\chi_i(g)|^2}{|C(g)|}=k\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{|\chi(g_j)|}{|C(g_j)|}+\frac{|G|}{2|C(g)|}<k$,where $g_1,...,g,..,g_κ$ are cojugation representatives.
I also cannot make something up from here either.
Any tip or help would be greatly appreciated ,thank you  very much !

$C(g)$ is a subgroup of $G$. What is its index?

Write $|G| = |C_G(g)| |G : C_G(g)|$.

"The question goes: ..." Please check as the second sentence you write makes no sense. Is that sum meant to equal something?

oops sorry i just made the edit !

So if we have $|G|<2|C(g)| \Rightarrow |G:C(g)|<2 \Rightarrow |G:C(g)|=1$ and thus G must be abelian .(?)@the_fox

For any subset $A$ of $G$, $C_G(A)$ is a subgroup of $G$. For finite $G$, no proper subgroup can have more than half as many elements as $G$.

@GGG Well, no. $G = C_G(g)$ implies just that $g$ lies in the centre of $G$.

Yeah u r right , I read the definition of C(g) again and it makes sense. Thank you very much ! @the_fox
